# Is there a way to use multilabel classification but take as correct when the model predicts only one label in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, classification

I have a dataset of weather forecasts and am trying to make a model that predicts which forecast will be more accurate the next day.

In order to do so, my y output is of the form y=[1,0,1,0] because I have the forecasts of 4 different organizations. 1 represents that this is the best forecast for the current record and more 'ones' means that multiple forecasts had the same best prediction.

My problem is that I want to create a model that trains on these data but also learns that only predicting 1 value correctly is 100% correct answer as I only need to get as a result one of the best and equal forecasts. I believe that the way I am doing this 'shaves' accuracy from my evaluation. Is there a way to implement this in keras?  The architecture of the neural network is totally experimental and there is no specific reason why I chose it. This is the code I wrote. My train dataset consists of 6463 rows × 505 columns.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(150, activation='relu',activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.0001)))
model.add(Dense(100,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,  activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(24,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax')) 


#LSTM
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
X_train_sc =X_train_sc.reshape((X_train_sc.shape[0], 1, X_train_sc.shape[1]))
X_test_sc = X_test_sc.reshape((X_test_sc.shape[0], 1,X_test_sc.shape[1]))
```

```
#validation set
x_val=X_train.iloc[-2000:-1300,0:505]
y_val=y_train[-2000:-1300]

x_val_sc=scaler.transform(x_val)

# reshape input to be 3D for LSTM[samples, timesteps, features]
x_val_sc =x_val_sc.reshape((x_val_sc.shape[0], 1, x_val_sc.shape[1]))
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

```
history= model.fit(x=X_train_sc, y=y_train ,validation_data=(x_val_sc,y_val), epochs=300, batch_size=24)
```

```
print(model.evaluate(X_test_sc,y_test))
yhat= model.predict(X_test_sc)
```

My accuracy is ~44%

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make prediction of form `[1,0,1,0]` ie. the model should predict the probabiliyt of belong to each of the 4 classes then it is called multi-label classification. What you have coded for is multi-class classification.

## Muti-label classification

Your last layer will be a dense layers of size 4 for each class, with sigmod activation. You will use a `binary_crossentropy` loss.

```
x = np.random.randn(100,10,1)
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,4))

model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,1), return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8,  activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x,y)
```

Check

```
print (model.predict(x))
```

Output

```
array([[0.5196002 , 0.52978194, 0.5009601 , 0.5036485 ],
       [0.508756  , 0.5189857 , 0.5022978 , 0.50169533],
       [0.5213044 , 0.5254892 , 0.51159555, 0.49724004],
       [0.5144601 , 0.5264933 , 0.505496  , 0.5008205 ],
       [0.50524575, 0.5147699 , 0.50287664, 0.5021702 ],
       [0.521035  , 0.53326863, 0.49642274, 0.50102305],
.........
```

As you can see the probabilities for each prediction do not sum up to one, rather each value is a probability of it belonging to the corresponding class. So if the probability > 0.5 you can say that it belong to the class.

On the other hand if you use `softmax`, the probabilies sum up to 1 ie. it belongs to the single class for which it has value > 0.5.

Comment: Actually I want to train on y that has [1,0,1,0] form but make predictions that have [1,0,0,0] form (ie return only one correct value). Do those things you said apply to this case too? And if so, should i keep the categorical accuracy as accuracy metric?

Comment: @orestisgiokas theoretically it is wrong to train on  multi-label and do predictions as multi-class. However as a hack why dont you just do `argmax` on the on multi-label prediction of the model and assign it to the class which is highest confident ?

Comment: i thought of it, but i was wondering if there was a trick to implement what i need in the training process, so that while the model is training if it makes a prediction relevant to [1,0,0,0] it wont drop the training accuracy. In other words i need to train my model on considering either of [1,0,1,0]  [1,0,0,0] and [0,0,1,0] as 100% correct during the training process